# Issue with string match when having square brackets in the operands strings

Tags: tcl

This looks as expected:

```
set a 1
puts [string match $a $a]
>> 1
```

However I find this unexpected:

```
set b {[1]}
puts [string match $b $b]
>> 0
```

Can you help explain the above behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `[1]` is a bracket expression that matches the characters inside the brackets.  In this case, the only string that will match the pattern is `1`.

```
% set b {[1]}
[1]
% puts [string match $b $b]
0
% puts [string match $b "1"]
1
%
```

If you'd like to compare two strings to see if they are identical, use `string equal ...` instead.

If you are in a unix shell environment, `man n string` or `man 3tcl string` should bring up a manual page with details about the `string` command.

Comment: The documentation is [online](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm) too.